# Conectar a Windows server y listar los archivos de una carpeta. (D:/) usando PHP

Tags: php

Buenas a todos,

Tengo una duda de como conectar mediante **PHP** a un servidor Windosw(No es Web), y listar los archivos de una carpeta que esta en su disco D:

- Tengo el usuario y la contraseña de dicho servidor.
- El servidor esta dentro de la red.

Gracias por su ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

vale inserta este codigo en tu php

```html
<iframe src="c:\" width="600" height="300"></iframe>
```

si la ruta esta en otra carpeta la apuntas ya bien sea en red o en otro disco.

Comment: Hola Ivan, recuerda que el codigo es una herramienta más. Lo importante de las respuestas es la explicacion. Mira [answer] para mejorarla. Un saludo